# Django query to fetch multiple GenericRelation objects for multiple objects

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-queryset

I need to make quite complex query in Django to display some information from two models.
There is FanGroup model, where I have few instances (let's say 5 and it's fixed) of this model. Each FanGroup model except few basic information contains GenericReleation to Fan model. For each FanGroup instance I could own few Fan instances (this is variable from 1 to many Fans assigned to each FanGroup).

FanGroup model:

```
class FanGroup(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    default_state = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    fans = GenericRelation(Fan, related_query_name='fan_controller')
```

Fan model:

```
class Fan(models.Model):
    fan_inventory_id = models.CharField(max_length=16)
    manufacture = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    model = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
```

I'd like to display in one View all the Fans belonging to FanGroup. How to combine the data to display this in single query?

I could do it dirty, making simple queries for Fan model with filters to FanGroup, but this is not very dynamic solution and not very elegant.

Comment: I don't think if there's a way that you can do this using Django orm. maybe you can use pivot in raw sql query. or handle it in python and create data tables

Comment: Is it not enough to do: `Fan.objects.filter(content_type__pk=ContentType.objects.get_for_model(FanGroup).id)`? This will get all fans that are linked to a `FanGroup`

Comment: Thanks @BrianDestura This is the way to extract whole list of Fans. Now I will handle this linking Fan object_id and desired FanGroup.

Comment: Yep, then you can add another filter for the designed fan group so: `Fan.objects.filter(content_type__pk=ContentType.objects.get_for_model(FanGroup).id, object_id__in=FanGroup.objects.filter(<desired_fan_group_filter>))`